# tensorflow next_batch vs custom next_batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to write a function that can get batches of data, similar to tensorflow's next_batch.

next_batch can be seen here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py

This is the code that I wrote.

```
class Sampler:

def __init__(self, data):        
    self.x, self.y = data
    self.N, = self.y.shape
    self.start = 0
    self.shuffle = np.arange(self.N)
    np.random.shuffle(self.shuffle)
    self.x = self.x[self.shuffle]
    self.y = self.y[self.shuffle]

def sample(self, s):
    start = self.start
    end = np.minimum(start+s, self.N)
    data = (self.x[start:end], self.y[start:end])
    self.start += s   
    if self.start >= self.N - 1:
        self.start = 0
        np.random.shuffle(self.shuffle)
        self.x = self.x[self.shuffle]
        self.y = self.y[self.shuffle]
    return data
```

I feel that this is a natural approach, but while I can get 99%+ accuracy with classification using next_batch, I can only get around 50% using my "sample" function.

Could anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code does almost exactly the same thing as the next_batch function from the mnist example. The only differences being that the DataSet class in the example flattens input data from (x,y,z,1) into (x,y*z) and then also normalizes all the data from [0,256] to [0,1]. Neither of these should effect accuracy immediately, but depending on how you are training they could have an effect.

Comment: Thank you so much -- this fixed my problem. I'd mark this as the correct answer but it is a comment so I think I can't do that. Please feel free to write it to an answer, I'll check mark it! :) Thanks so much again.

Comment: np, thanks for the $5 :) jkjk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct cp from my comment but...

As far as I can tell, your code does almost exactly the same thing as the next_batch function from the mnist example. The only differences being that the DataSet class in the example flattens input data from (x,y,z,1) into (x,y*z) and then also normalizes all the data from [0,256] to [0,1]. Neither of these should effect accuracy immediately, but depending on how you are training they could have an effect.